# How to redirect an import in python

Tags: python-3.x, sys

I have a code and an import in many files have `from test import testfunc`. I now want to change this to `from lib import flow` without touching the files and only touching the startup script. How do i do this? By the way this is python 3

I have tried `sys.module['test.testfunc'] = lib.flow` but this does nothing

```
from test import testfunc
test01 = testfunc()
```

How to make it like

```
from lib import flow
test01 = flow()
```

File dirs

```
root
 ├─main.py
 ├─lib.py
 ├─test.py
 └─test_plugins
    └─foo.py
```

main.py

```
from lib import flow
sys.module['test.func'] = lib.flow
import test_plugins.foo
```

lib.py

```
def flow(input):
    print(input)
```

test.py

```
def func(test):
    print(type(test))
```

test_plugins/foo.py

```
from test import func
func(007)
```

But now i want foo.py to do

```
from lib import flow
flow(007)
```

Comment: I think it would be much easier to get help if you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)